# How do I use the overflow property in a grid?

Tags: html, css, overflow

When I try to hide overflow of border-radius of child element in grid, it doesn't work. It does however work with flex.

What I tried so far:

I put `overflow: hidden;` in the parent element, but nothing happens

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 2fr);
  margin: 10em auto;
  max-width: 40vw;
  min-height: 40vh;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Head</div>
  <div>main</div>
  <div>foot</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can be to not use body as parent of your elements like this. Rather, wrap them in another div.

To exclude this "new" parent, you can use the not selector on the div selector you already have

```
div:not(.parent) {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 2fr);
  margin: 10em auto;
  max-width: 40vw;
  min-height: 40vh;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div:not(.parent) {
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Head</div>
  <div>main</div>
  <div>foot</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that works, apparently newbie mistake :)

Comment: @user20917515 please accept the answer if it solved your problem (the gray check-icon).